# WPF Binding to a property of an usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, binding

I have an usercontrol, which have a property **Results**. This usercontrol should show this *ObservableCollection*. I think the XAML-Code of the usercontrol doesn't matter. The Code-Behind look like that:

```vb
Public Property Results() As ObservableCollection(Of ResultModel)
    Get
        Return GetValue(ResultsProperty)
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of ResultModel))
        SetValue(ResultsProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly ResultsProperty As DependencyProperty = _
                       DependencyProperty.Register("Results", _
                       GetType(ObservableCollection(Of ResultModel)), GetType(ResourcesGridData), _
                       New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing))
```

In my MainView.xaml I have the following XAML-Code to show the usercontrol:

```
<controls:ResourcesGridData Results="{Binding Path=ResultsToShow}" />
```

I want to bind the **ResultsToShow** property of the MainViewModel to the property of the usercontrol.

But now I get the following error:

> System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression ist kein Wert des Typs ASSESS.Data.ResultModel und kann in dieser generischen Auflistung nicht verwendet werden.

I try to translate it:

> System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression is not a value of the type ASSESS.Data.ResultModel and can not be used in this generic list.

Comment: Is the MainViewModel the DataContext of this UserControl (ResourcesGridData), or is it actually associated with the main window/parent control?

Comment: The comment help me alot. I didn't know, the DataContext of the MainView is automatically the DataContext of the usercontrol

Comment: So have you solved your problem? :)

Comment: Yes, Thank you for this cause for thought! :)

Comment: Please post an answer and accept it to mark this question as resolved. (*Also get an English Visual Studio, localized software is a pain*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's very simple. In my case, I don't need any properties in the usercontrol code-behind.

In the MainView I simply write this:

```xml
<controls:ResourcesGridData />
```

and in the usercontrol:

```xml
ItemsSource="{Binding ResultsToShow}"
```

I directly bind to the Property of the DataContext of the MainView.